# c# import List(T) from Library to main

Tags: c#, list, dll, dllimport, n-tier-architecture

im having problems with importing a List(T) method that add all the data to a List.
I need to call it in main and full my list with the data, but always get error like this...

Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<mylib.myclass>' to
'mylib.myclass'

There is a better way to do it or can i edit this code to success import?

- CLASS LIBRARY CODE

```
 public static EstatisticasEquipas InserirEstatisticasEquipas(List<EstatisticasEquipas> listEstatisticaEquipas, List<Equipa> listEquipas, List<Jogos> listJogos)
        {
            List<EstatisticasEquipas> listEstatisticaEquipa = new List<EstatisticasEquipas>();

            foreach (Equipa equipa in listEquipas)
            {
                foreach (Jogos jogo in listJogos)
                {
                 // DO SOMETHING...
                }
             }
      Return listEstatisticaEquipas
```

- PROGAM MAIN CODE

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Jogos> listJogos = new List<Jogos>();
            listJogos = InserirJogos();

            List<Equipa> listEquipas = new List<Equipa>();
            listEquipas = InserirEquipas(listJogos);

            List<EstatisticasEquipas> listEstatisticaEquipas = new List<EstatisticasEquipas>();
            listEstatisticaEquipas = EstatisticasEquipas.InserirEstatisticasEquipas(listEstatisticaEquipas, listEquipas, listJogos);
```

Comment: `InserirEstatisticasEquipas` returns a single `EstatisticasEquipas`, not a List, but you're trying to assign it to one (`listEstatisticaEquipas`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Broots already mentioned the function signature for `InserirEstatisticasEquipas` requires that you return a single instance of `EstatisticasEquipas`, but the variable that you attempt to return is actually a `List<EstatisticasEquipas>`.

How you want to solve it depends on what you're trying to achieve, but the code in your main program indicates that you actually want a list, so you can simply change the return type of the function like so:

```cs
public static List<EstatisticasEquipas> InserirEstatisticasEquipas(List<EstatisticasEquipas> listEstatisticaEquipas, List<Equipa> listEquipas, List<Jogos> listJogos)
```

Always make sure that your function returns the type that you set in its signature.

Most IDE's will help you find errors like that, if you're not already using one I suggest downloading Visual Studio Code or some other IDE and installing the language extension for C#.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, it worked... im new with c# but now give me this error:
"Exception Thrown - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

-CLASS LIBRARY CODE

```
public static void TotalPontos()
        {
            listEstatisticaEquipas.Sort((x, y) => y.Pontos.CompareTo(x.Pontos));
            foreach (EstatisticasEquipas estEquipa in listEstatisticaEquipas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(estEquipa.Equipa.Nome + " - " + estEquipa.Pontos);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey just to let you know, if you believe my answer solved your initial question please mark it as the accepted answer, this way other people looking for the question will be able to find it. If you have any other questions you can [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

In regards to your latest question, there's a good change you haven't assigned a value to your variable `listEstatisticaEquipas` yet, which means it is 'NULL'. Trying to perform operations on objects that are NULL cause this exception.